# is there any standard equation or parameter for this family of curves?

Tags: functions

I have some data which on plotting looks like the following:

[image]

at some value of    'a', all X data give Y=0 (bottom line)

at another value of 'a', all X data give Y=1 (top blue line)

and all the remaining curves are sandwiched between Y=0 and Y=1 as shown,
but the problem is that all in-between curves are not straight lines as u can see in the red, green and violet one.

I just want to have an equation or parameter which can define this complete set of curves.

Looking at the curves, it just felt that there may be some standard function already to describe this. Does any of u guys know any such function?

And if there is no such function already, is there any way to find an expression for this family of curves?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: maybe some twist of $f_n(x) = x^n$ on $x \in (0,1)$? For $n=0$ you get all ones, for $n \to \infty$, you get all zeros and all else is in between?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that that we can find a family of ''simple'' functions that exactly fit your points.

As a possible approximation I suggest the family of functions of the form:

$y=a\left(\tanh (x-b)+c \right)$ ( see http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+y%3D2+%28-tanh%28x-5%29%2B1%29 for a plot)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this tanh(x) is having a complete S-shape just like a Sigmoid function isn't it (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SigmoidFunction.html); whereas my data is not having a complete S-shape.